# Problemas con vue 3 y VS code

Tags: vue.js, vscode

Estoy trabajando con vue 3 y al abrir el código nuevamente en vscode este ha dejado de autocompletarme el código en los archivos .vue ya no me completa las etiquetas HTML ni el css, cosa q hacía . Al igual q ya no me marca los errores en el código javascript. He buscado pero no he podido encontrar una solución a este problema . Las extensiones q uso para vue son vue 3 features Volar y vue snippets ambas están habilitadas

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.